# How to use (THIS=x OR THAT=Y) AND OTHER=Z with find command

Tags: linux, find

I'm converting my video library to x265 from x264 using the following:

It looks for x264 anywhere in the file name, but excludes any that begin x265 as these are the files which have been completed.

```
sudo find /mnt/local/int001/media/TV/ -name '*x264*.mkv' -and -not -name 'X265*.mkv' -print0 | xargs -0 /usr/local/bin/ConvertTo265.sh
```

I've found a lot that are tagged as h264 (Encoding Standard) rather than x264 (Specific Implementation of h264) as well as other variations.

How do I enhance my search for:

Does NOT contain 'X265*', but contains ONE or more of the following:

- '*x264*'
- '*h264*'
- '*h.264*'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find /mnt/local/int001/media/TV/ \
  \( -name '*[xXhH]264*.mkv' -o -name '*[xXhH].264*.mkv' \) \
  ! -name '*[xX]265*' -type f -exec /usr/local/bin/ConvertTo265.sh {} +
```

Here replacing your GNUisms (`-and`, `-not`, `-print0`/`xargs -0`) with their standard equivalents (`-a` or nothing as that's the default, `!`, `-exec cmd {} +`).

Replace `mkv` with `[mM][kK][vV]` if you want to match on the extension case-insensitively as well (or use `-iname` if using GNU `find` or compatible).

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
ConvertTo265.sh ./**/(#i)(*x265*~*[xh](.|)264*).mkv(D.)
```

Comment: You answered the question perfectly, thanks.  But as you've provided all the variations in the first part of the OR, there is no need for it.  So I condensed down to >> find /mnt/local/int001/media/public/Audio\ \&\ Visual\ Library/Visual/Video/TV/ \
  -name '*[xXhH]264*.[mM][kK][vV]' \
  ! -name '*[xX]265*' -type f -exec /usr/local/bin/ConvertTo265.sh {} +

Comment: @aSystemOverload, that's missing the h.264 variants though. The _or part_ was about `x264` or `x.264` (without or with the dot).

Comment: DOH!  Thanks for pointing out the obvious that I missed LOL.  Thanks again, was clear, concise and worked first time.

Comment: can you add the closing single quote >> -o -name '*[xXhH].264*.mkv' <<  I can't EDIT it for a single character.

Comment: Initially I could not get your full version (after re-adding the -or to capture x.263 etc..) to work, then I realised you'd missed the closing single quote.  But it still didn't work.  Then I realised, GDrive where I'd kept this snippet, had added a curly single quote, not a straight single quote.  After copying/pasting one of your quotes, it works fine. (damn quotes)... Thanks again.